# Why does a merge show no changes in a patch?

Tags: git

I'm combing the logs of a git repo and I'm finding merge commits with conflicts listed in the comments, but no files actually changed as part of the merge commit. How and when can this happen? The merge has two parents and they are definitely different, so how can no file changes be listed in the patch?

Comment: How do you know that `no files actually changed as part of the merge commit`? Do you just do `git show` on merge commit? You should do `git show <PARENT_1_SHA1>..<PARENT_2_SHA1>` to show changes introduced by `merge commit`.

Comment: I run `git show` on the merge commit and it lists no files. If I run `git show <parent_1_sha1>..<parent_2_sha1> ` on the two parent commits, it shows an addition of 4 lines to particular file. However, if you look at that file from the merge commit, those 4 lines do not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `git show` on a *merge* commit (one with two or more parents) shows a "combined diff".  The [documentation for `git show`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html#_diff_format_for_merges) has this key paragraph rather hidden:

> Note that *combined diff* lists only files which were modified from all parents.

That is, suppose that merge `3333333...` has parents `1111111...` and `2222222...`, and that:

```
git diff 1111111 3333333
```

would show changes to both `README` and `file1.txt`, and:

```
git diff 2222222 3333333
```

would show changes to both `README` and `file2.txt`.  Suppose further that the changes in `README` are *different* so that the merge had to combine both changes.  Then:

```
git show 3333333
```

will show you `README` (because `3333333:README` is different from both `1111111:README` *and* `2222222:README`), but will *not* show you either `file1.txt` or `file2.txt` (because that's the same in `3333333` as in either `1111111` or `2222222`).

In this case (files with conflicts), it means that the conflicts were resolved by choosing only one of the multiple parents' versions of each file, rather than combining changes from each parent.  (This is often an error.)

It's even worse when using `git log -p`, which—for merge commits—skips the diff listing entirely by default.

You can modify the way that any of the diff-showing commands, including `git log -p`, shows you a merge [with any of `-c`, `--cc`, or `-m`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html#_combined_diff_format).  (The `--cc` option is the default for `git show`.  Note that there are two `-` characters in front of `cc` but only one in front of `c` and `m`.)  However, only `-m` actually shows you *all* the differences, by (in effect) splitting a commit into multiple virtual commits, each with one of the *N* parents.